# Are there light circuits that can be cut and still work?

Tags: light

I need a way to have a light circuit that can be severed/cut and still work up to the point that it got cut.  I know that rope lights work that way, but they can only be cut at certain points, right?

Is there any way to have a length of LED lights that still work if I cut it at a random spot?

Comment: Could the cut/sever result in the wires being shorted?

Comment: That is what a ring main does.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN9GNV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. LED flexible strip lights typically consist of three LEDs and series resistors wired between the positive and negative rails.*

Each segment of these LED strips is wired as shown in Figure 1. You can cut anywhere along the strip, including through an LED, but it should be obvious from Figure 1 that cutting anywhere along the D1, D2, D3 chain will open-circuit that whole section. All the LEDs up to that section will light but the one, two or three left on that section will not.

> Is there any way to have a length of LED lights that still work if I cut it at a random spot?

I think the above schematic and text should give you a good understanding.

Comment: I've seen 5V LED strips with individual LEDs and resistors, but only once and never again.. the OP can design them and have them built

Comment: I guess anything can be built and, for example, the multi-coloured strips have more conductors but there should be enough info there. I've learned to be careful how to word things in my answers - see "typically" in the Figure 1 caption. ;^)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply your answer was incomplete, just helping the OP understand that although 3 LEDs in series is the de-facto standard, viable alternatives exist and/or can be built. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wiring up the leds in parallel would work. Depending on what type of wire you use, the powersupply might get shorted